# Accessing CAS server running behind proxy server

Tags: cas

I configured **CAS** server behind my company proxy; While validating using `Saml11TicketValidationFilter` it is giving

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException
```

This is because **CAS** client is not able to access validating URL which is behind proxy. Can some body help me to configure proxy in **CAS** client.